# How would I go about tracing this java arrays code snippet

Tags: java, arrays, addition, system.out

```
public static void addBonus(double[] array, double bonus)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < array.length; k++)
   {
        array[k] = array[k] + bonus;
   }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
    double[] scores = { 45.6, 67.8, 89.4 };
    addBonus(scores, 3.0);
    System.out.print(scores[2]);
}
```

I see that this is an execution of a method that changes the array contents, and I start off by running through the loop and am fine until I get to the + bonus part, I know array[k] would be 45.6 for [0] and so on but I'm not sure if 3.0 is what I should be adding. I guess what my issue is, is not understanding the line addBonus(scores, 3.0). 
Thank you for your time, I'm relatively new to java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line `addBonus(scores, 3.0)` you are calling the method `addBonus` with arguments `scores` & `3.0`. So these will be copied to their respective parameters of the method `addBonus(double[] array, double bonus)`. So `bonus` will have the value `3.0`.

Here `array[k] = array[k] + bonus;` you are adding `3.0` to all array elements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes each of your array element will be increment by 3.0 bonus which your are passing in addBonus(scores, 3.0);